# Log Forging in C#

Tags: c#, log-forging

Our Product is gone through Security Testing .They have given some references from code for Log Forging.

One of those is :

```
DataRow dr = new DataRow();

var data=Convert.ToString(dataRow["ColumnName"]); // <--
```

I have Google, but got that if any information is logged which is not secure.

But here nothing is logged .

Please suggest your views.

Comment: Maybe this can help you, [How to fix log forging in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47771586/how-to-fix-log-forging-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Will `dataRow.Field<string>("ColumnName")` get flagged?

Comment: @ParrishHusband : No

Comment: @UmutÇömlekçioğlu : Thanks for the reply I have gone through this link but it didn't linked to my problem